# vlc problem with chromecast

Tags: vlc, chromecast

Using VLC 3.0.16 on xubuntu 22.04 to cast video to chromecast, does not work with all files. It works with some (AVI) files, but with some other (AVI) file just connects normally, but video is black and playback seems stopped.

I found some old question about a very similar problem, but it seems that those problems where solved by update but here I'm on an updated machine.

UPDATE: If I remove audio, then the video is casted, if I put on the audio again then the black screen comes back.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media

Comment: Has there been an answer for this yet? I am having the exact same problem with multiple file types (wmv, aci, mp4, ect.) on a fresh install of ubuntu 22.04.1. However on my older machine that has been upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.1 from 18 and everything in between has no problem rendering to a chromecast (with audio). This makes me think it's missing a codec or plugin. any ideas? also is there a way to get the list of plugins in a text file so I can compare the two machines easily?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved! Upgrade to VLC 3.0.18.

1. Purge all installation files of VLC by opening a terminal and running these commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge vlc
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
2. Update the repositories:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Open the software app and make sure that VLC is not installed.
4. If you have not already installed all codecs run the following:

   ```
   sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
   ```
5. Now, I am not a fan of using `snap` but it seems to work (for this). Open the Software app and search for VLC.
6. Click on VLC to pull up the app's information. Be sure the source is set to *Ubuntu (snap)* in the top right (not *Ubuntu (deb)*).
7. Scroll down to make sure that the version is 3.0.18. Then simply click *Install* and start streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue.

VLC 3.0.18 installed from Snap is missing this package:

```
sudo apt install libaribb24-0
```