# VLC not working when displaying to Chromecast

Tags: video, vlc, chromecast

since a few days, I can't display using VLC any video to Chromecast.

I have Ubunu 22.04 and VLC 3.0.18.
I open my video with VLC, I change the renderer to my chromacast device and the video simply stops playing: black screen both on VLC both on TV screen.

I tried also with other similar tool for casting like Kodi but still the same.
I still able to send something to Chromecast for example some web pages when I use Chrome, or youtube videos, but local videos are unavailable now.

Kindly ask you for your help.

Thank you,
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at:

1. [VLC is not working on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1445247/vlc-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-22-04)
2. [vlc problem with chromecast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419280/vlc-problem-with-chromecast)

Hope it helps. I didn't try Flatpack yet and didn't succeed with other recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue.

VLC 3.0.18 installed from Snap is missing this package:

```
sudo apt install libaribb24-0
```